# Blender not selecting edge (only vertices)

Tags: vertices, edges, extrude

When I select two connecting vertices it should highlight the edge in question for extrusion however, when I try selecting the vertices it won't highlight the edge in between resulting in extrusions like this (where only the vertices are extruded:
[image]

I realize this is a rookie mistake but I couldn't find anything online to help with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you have overlapping vertices so you think the selected vertices are linked by an edge but they are actually not

Comment: Thanks, I think u were right because after moving the vertices around I found there were overlapping vertices. Thanks a lot! Edit: It works now.

Comment: in that case you can easily fix the problem: Select all and Alt M > Merge by Distance, it will merge all the overlapping vertices